# Resource (Images & plists) bundling for Static library

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have created a static library for my application. Now, my application uses sources like plists & images which I am referring in my application.

How can I bundle those images and deliver them with the static library and also what changes do I need to do in my source loading code to load it from that bundle.

Right now I using [UIImage imageNamed:"my.png"] to load the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A library cannot have "resources". A library will just provide some algorithm or logic to get the things done. So you cannot include any resources with in your library. Along with your library, you have to distribute the resources also. Or else the app that is using the library must have the resources with the same name that you hard coded.

Comment: Thats true. How to create a resource bundle. Any idea?

Comment: No idea. I never came across such a typical scenario.

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly the reason to create a Framework - in a Framework you have:

- A static library (with binaries for
  simulator and phone melded together)
- Include files a user of the framework
  needs
- Resources the framework needs, which
  can be anything including .plist
  files, images or xib.

Edit:

Removed link that was dead.  You no longer need to know how to construct frameworks for iOS, because starting with iOS8 you can have Xcode create an iOS framework project.

In fact this is a great approach also, because frameworks can easily be imported into Playgrounds to call.

Comment: Thanks for the note, fixed up the answer to reflect Xcode updates.  The reason to use Frameworks remains the same; it's just easier than ever to do so!